# How to add check with multiple lines of Expense items in Quickbooks using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, quickbooks

So far i have been using the code found here to add a new check to QB:
https://pulseinfomatics.com/quickbooks-sdk-iaddcheck-using-vba-add-a-check-from-excel-or-access/

I can add the check OK but I need to add multiple lines of expense items to the check.  I have tried this code but it just uses the last item ("third") listed in the code (code just for testing how to do this).

```
smgr.OpenConnection "", "your appname"
smgr.BeginSession "", omDontCare
Dim qresp As IResponse
Dim rList As IResponseList
Dim chklist As ICheckRetList
Dim rMsg As IMsgSetRequest
Dim rMsgr As IMsgSetResponse
Dim iChk As ICheckAdd

Dim datChkDate As Date
Dim strCustRef As String

strCustRef = ""
datChkDate = Date

Set rMsg = smgr.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 13, 0)

Set iChk = rMsg.AppendCheckAddRq()
iChk.TxnDate.SetValue (datChkDate)
iChk.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue (strBankAccount)
iChk.PayeeEntityRef.FullName.SetValue (strCustName)
iChk.Address.Addr1.SetValue (strStreet1)
iChk.Address.Addr2.SetValue (strStreet2)
iChk.Address.City.SetValue (strCity)
iChk.Address.State.SetValue (strState)
iChk.Address.PostalCode.SetValue (strZip)
iChk.Memo.SetValue (strMemo)
Dim iExp As IExpenseLineAdd
Set iExp = iChk.ExpenseLineAddList.Append()

iExp.Amount.SetValue (curAmount)
iExp.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue (strAccount)
iExp.Memo.SetValue ("first")

'iExp.CustomerRef.FullName.SetValue (strCustRef)

iExp.Amount.SetValue (curAmount)
iExp.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue (strAccount)
iExp.Memo.SetValue ("Second")

iExp.Amount.SetValue (curAmount)
iExp.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue (strAccount)
iExp.Memo.SetValue ("Third")

Set rMsgr = smgr.DoRequests(rMsg)
strResponse = rMsgr.ToXMLString()

QBAddCheck = strResponse

Set rMsg = Nothing
Set iChk = Nothing
Set iExp = Nothing
Set rMsgr = Nothing

smgr.EndSession
smgr.CloseConnection
Set smgr = Nothing

End Function
```

This is a screen capture of the QB Pro 2017 window showing what I am trying to do:

[image: QB Pro 2017 write check screen]

How do you do this?

Thanks,
TD

Comment: I expect that between each set of SetValue code lines, need to move to another NewRecord row. Unfortunately, I have no idea how you would do that for QB sdk.

Comment: Maybe repeat the `Set iExp ...` line. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't done this myself - I believe I see the issue in your code.  if you are only getting the last value (in your example, the third value), it is because you need to precede each value creation with the code below.  otherwise, setting the value just resets the value of the line, but doesn't add a new line.

Also, if you expect anymore than 3 lines - I would suggest using a loop to go through all items and add the exact amount, instead of adding the numbers lines each time.

```
Set iExp = iChk.ExpenseLineAddList.Append()
iExp.Amount.SetValue (curAmount)
iExp.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue (strAccount)
iExp.Memo.SetValue ("first")

Set iExp = iChk.ExpenseLineAddList.Append()
iExp.Amount.SetValue (curAmount)
iExp.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue (strAccount)
iExp.Memo.SetValue ("Second")

Set iExp = iChk.ExpenseLineAddList.Append()
iExp.Amount.SetValue (curAmount)
iExp.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue (strAccount)
iExp.Memo.SetValue ("Third")
```

Comment: Were you able to try my suggestion above?  Just curious if it worked or not, as i am pursuing a similar project and i would like to know if i am on the right track.